# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

i have 2 file, data.h and data.m with connection db and method db.
When i implement a method i have a warning

***Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')
This is my code.***

in data.h

```
 - (id)initCity:(NSString *)pathDB: (NSInteger *)id_city: (NSString *)type;
 - (void)getCity:(NSString *)dbPath:(NSInteger *)id_city;
```

in data.m

```
- (id)initCity:(NSString *)pathDB: (NSInteger *)id_city: (NSString *)type
 {
  [self getCity:pathDB: id_city: type];
  return self;
 }

- (void)getCity:(NSString *)dbPath : (NSInteger *)id_city : (NSString *)type { .......
......
}
```

and where i call my method

```
NSString *mystring = @"string";
dataCity = [[Data alloc] initCity: defaultDBPath: selectedItem :mystring];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [dataCity objectAtIndex:0];
```

where wrong?
Thanks 
frank

Comment: From the code you've posted, I have to suggest that you get a book on Objective-C. Very little of your code makes sense, and I think that investing in learning the basics well is going to be well worth it. There are too many things to point out individually here to fix your code, but I'd say that taking it slow and making sure you understand all the concepts of the language would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

First of all NSInteger is an integer type, not an object, so you don't need a pointer.

Secondly, your method declarations are malformed. It should be something like this:

```
- (id)initCityWithPath:(NSString *)pathDB andId:(NSInteger)id_city andType:(NSString *)type;
- (void)getCityWithPath:(NSString *)dbPath andId:(NSInteger)id_city;
```

Comment: malformed is a good way to put it, gave me a headache looking at it.

Comment: I would have answered but I'm still trying to get my head round how he's written the methods :)

Comment: It's actually legal syntax to have methods with unnamed labels. `:` is a valid method name

Comment: Legal, yes. Try getting it though peer review though :)

Comment: Legal, yes... and a sure fire way to incur wrath from any experienced ObjC developer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (id)initCity:(NSString *)pathDB: (NSInteger *)id_city: (NSString *)type;
```

The name of this method is `initCity:::` which takes three parameters, `pathDB`, `id_city` and `type`. This is probably not what you want and probably not what anybody who has to look at your code wants. Objective-C gives you the ability to name the parameters of methods, and any method that does not name its parameters will always be suspicious<sup>1</sup>. For most Objective-C developers, `initCity:::` is not a good name for a method.

Secondly, initialiser methods should *always* start by invoking `[super init]` and assigning the result to `self`. There is seldom a reason not to do this (for example, when you are creating your own root class).

Third, your initialiser calls `getCity:::` (another poor name) which returns `void` and takes two input parameters and possibly one in/out or output parameter, this does not look like it will initialise your object properly. It is rare to see a method start with `get` unless it has an output parameter (e.g. `getBytes:length:`). In your case I think you may be using the wrong type, `NSInteger` is an alias for a 32-bit integer on 32-bit platforms and a 64-bit integer on 64-bit platforms. `NSInteger *` is therefore a pointer to such an integer. It's confusing, but this is different from `NSNumber` which is a *class* that encapsulates things like `NSInteger`.

No offence intended here, but from the code you provided above it seems that you lack some understanding of fundamental aspects of Objective-C. I would recommend reading a good book, following some reputable tutorials and having a look at some of Apple's example code before progressing.

---

<sub>1: For older runtimes, the root `Object` class declared in [`objc/Object.h`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/tags/gcc_3_4_6_release/libobjc/objc/Object.h?revision=111785&view=markup) had two methods called `forward::` and `performv::` which both contained an unnamed parameter, and these were used for message forwarding.</sub>

Comment: ... and the old Object also defined a -free method.  We don't talk about that much anymore. :)

Comment: Poor `Object`... nobody likes it any more. It was good being able to experiment with it but nowadays of course Cocoa and Objective-C are becoming more and more tightly coupled.

Comment: Given how dead simple Object was, if you really want to go there, implement your own base class!   The key is to *never* mix your base class (or Object subclasses) with NSObject derived classes.  There is very little of manual-retain-release runtime behavior that is assumed (I think you need to implement +initialize and, possibly, method forwarding maybe).